# How is called a callback given to jQuery bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code, will the trigger then call topbar.resize or will it just simply run the function contained in it? I assume there is a context difference between the two, or how does that work?

`jQuery.bind("hideBackstage", topbar.resize);`

**Edit:** How do I make it just simply call topbar.resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call will be equivalent to

```
topbar.resize.call(touchedElement, jqueryWrappedEvent);
```

That is the function "contained" in `topbar.resize` will be called with receiver (`this`) the element having received the event and with parameter the event (wrapped as a jquery event).

This is different from

```
topbar.resize()
```

because

- the receiver (`this`) won't be `topbar`
- an event is provided as parameter

**EDIT following your EDIT :**

If you just  want the call to be equivalent to `topbar.resize()`, simply do this :

```
jQuery.bind("hideBackstage", function(){topbar.resize()});
```

Comment: Do I need a semicolon after it?

Comment: If you mean before the last "}", the semicolon is implicit (it's inserted automatically). You may add it if you like, I personally don't add it in such a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery proxy or

```
jQuery.bind("hideBackstage", function(){
    topbar.resize.apply(topbar, arguments); // seting context as topbar for resize.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.proxy()` (which funnily enough is analogous to `Function.prototype.bind()`).

```
jQuery.bind("hideBackstage", $.proxy(topbar.resize, topbar));
```

However, you won't have access to the `event` object.